# Reflection casting

Tags: c#, reflection, casting

I have an object with some fields in it and I'm using reflection to iterate the fields of that object.  This object is get Serialized and Deserialized.  I'm writing the Deserialization routine now.  I want to iterate through the fields, grab the value from the deserializations SerializationInfo.  Before I started to implement Reflection, I did everything manually:

```
public SKA_MAP(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
{
    //Get the values from info and assign them to the appropriate properties
    DISP_SEGS = (int)info.GetValue("DISP_SEGS", typeof(int)); 
    //other fields followed
}
```

and now:

```
public SKA_MAP(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
{
    //Get the values from info and assign them to the appropriate properties
    //DISP_SEGS = (int)info.GetValue("DISP_SEGS", typeof(int));

    foreach (FieldInfo FI in this.GetType().GetFields())
    {
        FI.SetValue(this, info.GetValue(FI.Name, FI.GetType()));
    }
}
```

I get

> 'Invalid cast from 'System.Int32' to 'System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo'.'

OK, yes, but I put different casts in there "not shown" and nothing.

Comment: I think `FI.GetType()` should be `FI.FieldType`  Right now you're passing in the type of the `FieldInfo`.

Comment: FI.GetType() will return FieldInfo, as that is it's type

Comment: That worked?  I tried that.  I swear.  Now, I'm wondering how I tried it.  Cause, I was looking at that property in the list and at one point I said why use GetType()? But, I kept scolling through to see the list of properties and methods.  Anyhow, great ... You don't even have to type cast info, doing it that way.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you need the second parameter on info.GetValue() ? And I think the first parameter should be the instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
FI.SetValue(this, info.GetValue(this));
```

See documentation for [`GetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue) and [`SetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z33zd7h(v=vs.110).aspx)